# RxJs - last request with interval

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I wonder how to obtain in RxJS something like that below.

1. Every second request will be send to server.
2. Response can take different amount of time. (More than 1s for clarification)
3. But when only some response arrives all older unfinished requests are canceled and subscription will receive only this latest finished request's result.

It looks like **switchMap** doesn't work as i want. Because every next started request cancels previous one before its response. See code below.

```js
let counter = 0;
let times = [1200, 500];

let getSomePromise = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let i = counter;
    counter++;
    
    if (i < 2) {
      console.log('promise ' + i + ' start');
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i < 2) {    
        console.log('promise ' + i + ' finish');
        resolve(i);
      }
    }, times[i]);
  });
}


let ob = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => {
     return getSomePromise();
  });

let sub = ob.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('result ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

I get:

```
promise 0 start
promise 1 start
promise 0 finish
promise 1 finish
result 1
```

I want:

```
promise 0 start
promise 1 start
promise 0 finish
result 0
promise 1 finish
result 1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mergeMap()` operator to get the result you want. This operator subscribes to all inner Observables returned from its projection function and re-emits all their items.

However, as far as I understand your question you really want to use `switchMap()` (the point n. 3 describes exactly what `switchMap` does) but your expected output looks like you want `mergeMap()`.

See your updated code and its output:

```js
let counter = 0;
let times = [1200, 500];

let getSomePromise = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let i = counter;
    counter++;
    
    if (i < 2) {
      console.log('promise ' + i + ' start');
    }
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i < 2) {    
        console.log('promise ' + i + ' finish');
        resolve(i);
      }
    }, times[i]);
  });
}


let ob = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .mergeMap(() => {
     return getSomePromise();
  });

let sub = ob.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log('result ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still not exactly what i need. If first promise is resolved little after second promise subscribtion should never get first promise's result!

Comment: Then the output you want in your question is incorrect, right? You should never receive `result 0`.

Comment: It is correct because second request isn't finished yet. I want get latest possible result depending on request sending order.
Two cases: 
1. If second promise is finished as first, i want only its result, every result of previous requests are outdated so i don't need their.
2. if first promise is finished as first i want get its result in subscription and still wait for result of next request.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`.switchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) operator.

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
.switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.ajax(someUrl))
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```